# Magento 2.4.3 issues - compatibility issue with a shop by brand module

Tags: module, magento2.4

I have installed multiple shops by the brand module but they have a common issue after I upgraded to Magento 2.4.3... there is no issue on 2.4.2

composer require coderkube/brand:1.0.1 --no-update
composer update

So when I click on the brand, it supposes to list all the products under this brand. and please note, this extension creates an attribute for every product and we use brand attributes on the product.

The following error appears:

Error: Call to a member function getOptionsData() on null in /usr/share/nginx/html/sample.com.uk/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml:90

and in line 90, this is the content of the code below:

```
<?php $optionsData = $block->getData('viewModel')->getOptionsData($_product); ?>
```

Please note, this only happens in Magento 2.4.3 not 2.4.2 and this error only happens when I click on one brand to list the product under this brand[image]

[image]

Comment: Share the code of the xml file for this page of that extension.

Comment: Hi Dhiren, i am not sure where this xml file located, but i have shared this entire extension at link below:

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/iqm05vkujdj5mls/coderkube-brand-1.0.1.zip?dl=0

Comment: make sure if your module has "ViewModel" folder and you don't missed  to upload "viewModel" folder.

Comment: Its possible that the function changed for that specific plugin. Check your plugin for getOptionsData() function and see where the data is coming in from.

Answer (score 2):

In your XML file, you have to add ViewModel for Layernavigation.

```
<referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
    <block class="Vendor\Custom\Block\Navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" as="navigation" before="-" template="Magento_LayeredNavigation::layer/view.phtml">
        <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\State" name="catalog.navigation.state" as="state" template="Magento_LayeredNavigation::layer/state.phtml" />
        <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\FilterRenderer" name="catalog.navigation.renderer" as="renderer" template="Magento_LayeredNavigation::layer/filter.phtml">
        <arguments>
                <argument name="product_layer_view_model" xsi:type="object">Magento\LayeredNavigation\ViewModel\Layer\Filter</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>

<referenceBlock name="your_product_list_block_name">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="viewModel" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\ViewModel\Product\OptionsData</argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue after updated magento version.

To solve it i was passed viewModel argument in layout file.

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="{{vendor}}\{{module}}\Block\Index\Collection" name="custom.list" as="custom_product_list" template="{{vendor_module}}::product/customlist.phtml">
                ...
                <argument name="viewModel" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\ViewModel\Product\OptionsData</argument>
                </arguments>
                ...     
            </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

Answer (score -1):

The Error is due to this line,

> $optionsData = $block->getViewModel();

Confirm into your system, from any extension you set the `ViewModel` for the product view page.

Comment: Hi Dhiren, how to check that? I have provided that full code for that brand extension now.                  ...........    https://www.dropbox.com/s/iqm05vkujdj5mls/coderkube-brand-1.0.1.zip?dl=0

Comment: not sure where should i look??? I want to repeat that this issue only happens when i upgrade magento to 2.4.3. this issue does NOT happen in magento 2.4.2

Comment: Too resolve the Issues, please learn about "ViewModel" concept so you get idea.